# IP address visible in browser's "Inspect Element"

Tags: networking, iis, webserver, ip, windows-8.1

I've recently started hosting my own website on a machine on my network.

Whenever anyone goes to my site and does "Inspect Element" my external IP address is visible to everyone. This seems like a huge issue..

I was wondering if there was some way to hide this so that everyone doesn't have that kind of direct access to my network.

If anyone needs to know, I've "purchased" my domain name from no-ip.com and I'm running Windows 8.1 and using IIS 8 to host the site.

Comment: Exactly what are you seeing? And why do you think this is an issue?

Comment: I may be a little to green here, so excuse me if I am. If my site is accessed by a machine not on my network and "Inspect" the page it shows my router's IP address. I was thinking that is a security risk since 1) there are ports forwarded so there is access to the machine and 2) if someone gets through the security within my router (since they have its IP) that would allow them on my home network. I wasn't exactly sure how big of an issue it is, but it SEEMS unsafe.

Comment: If you're going to be hosting services, like a website, that are publicly available, your IP must be known publicly.  You should, however, be running a proper firewall, a secure gateway and properly patched server software to prevent bad actors from accessing your private network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do your public IP address can easily be found via ping, traceroute or even DNS lookup. This is because computers use IP addresses to communicate with each other, so it must determine that from a DNS (Domain Name Server) in order to know where to connect to. For example, pinging Google displays:

```
PING www.google.com (74.125.239.114) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Try typing http://74.125.239.114 into a web browser and see what happens.
Much like how on your local network each machine has an IP address, the Internet is just a huge network of computers (routers usually) which all need a way to locate them -- their address! Just think how inefficient it would be to keep a database on your computer to match every site in the world with its IP address!

If you're concerned about security a great tip is to avoid using Windows -- especially if you're opening your machine up to the internet. I'd recommend dual booting any Linux distro and running an Apache web server, which is [very easy to set up](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html). It will take a bit more work but you'll find that Linux is much more suited to be any kind of server! Good luck, hope this helped!

Comment: I'm sorry, but just running Linux does not make things any more secure.  For one apache runs just fine in Windows too.  It's also pretty easy to create an insecure Linux server configuration if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: No, I totally agree. It's just that Windows has a lot of security vulnerabilities in general and is targeted much more frequently due to it being more widely used. With Linux on the other hand, you can know everything that's going on with your system and know where to patch the holes.